# MYSQL Update query using a temporary table when an equivalent select query does not

Tags: mysql, sql-update, innodb, temp-tables, explain

I have a MYSQL table Foo which has Primary key on id, and 2 other non primary keys on different columns.
[Fiddle "select" example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cb4/9)

My actual table contains many millions of rows so the behaviour of the explain is different, ie. it uses an Index_Merge on the 2 non primary indexes.

When I run the following Explain Update statement:

```
explain UPDATE Foo
SET readyState = 1 
WHERE readyState = 0
AND productName = 'OpenAM'
LIMIT 30;
```

The Extra column contains "Using Temporary".

When I run the equivalent explain Select statement:

```
Explain Select id, productName, readyState
FROM Foo
WHERE readyState = 0
AND productName = 'OpenAM'
Limit 30;
```

The Extra column **does not** contain "Using Temporary".

The effect of this on my actual table is that when I update, there is a temporary table being created with several million rows as they are all matching the conditions of the update before the Limit 30 kicks in. The update takes 4-5 seconds whereas the select only takes ~0.001s as it does not create the temp table of the merged index. I understand that the Update will also need to update all 3 indexes (Primary + 2 non primary used in the query) but I would be shocked if it took 4 seconds to update 30 index rows in 3 indexes.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to force the Update to not use the unneccessary Temporary table? I was under the impression that MYSQL treated an Update query plan the same way as a select.

If the temp table is required for Update and not for Select, why?

EDIT:

```
Show Create Table (removed a heap of columns since it is a very wide table):
    CREATE TABLE Item (
      ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      ImportId int(11) NOT NULL,
      MerchantCategoryName varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      HashId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      Processing varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
      Status int(11) NOT NULL,
      AuditWho varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      AuditWhen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (ID),
      KEY idx_Processing_Item (Processing),
      KEY idx_Status_Item (Status),
      KEY idx_MerchantCategoryName_Item (MerchantCategoryName),
      KEY fk_Import_Item (ImportId),
      KEY fk_Hash_Item (HashId),
      CONSTRAINT fk_Hash_Item FOREIGN KEY (HashId) REFERENCES Hash (ID),
      CONSTRAINT fk_Import_Item FOREIGN KEY (ImportId) REFERENCES Import (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12004589 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Update statement

```
    explain UPDATE Item
    SET Processing = 'd53dbc91-eef4-11e5-a3a6-06f88beef4f3',
        Status = 2,
        AuditWho = 'name',
        AuditWhen = now()
    WHERE EventId = 1
    AND Processing is null
    AND Status = 1
    LIMIT 30;
```

Results:

```
'id','select_type','table','type','possible_keys','key','key_len','ref','rows','Extra',
'1','SIMPLE','Item','index_merge','idx_Processing_Item,idx_Status_Item,fk_Import_Item','idx_Processing_Item,idx_Status_Item,fk_Import_Item','111,4,4',\N,'1362610','Using intersect(idx_Processing_Item,idx_Status_Item,fk_Import_Item); Using where; Using temporary',
```

Select Query

```
    explain select ID from Item where Status = 1 and Processing is null and ImportId = 1 limit 30;
```

Results:

```
'id','select_type','table','type','possible_keys','key','key_len','ref','rows','Extra',
'1','SIMPLE','Item','index_merge','idx_Processing_Item,idx_Status_Item,fk_ImportEvent_Item','idx_Processing_Item,idx_Status_Item,fk_Import_Item','111,4,4',\N,'1362610','Using intersect(idx_Processing_ItemPending,idx_Status_ItemPending,fk_ImportEvent_ItemPending); Using where; Using index',
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is asking for unpredictable results.

Comment: For this particular query, I dont care which rows are updated or selected, I just need any 30 rows updated. I Also just did the explain with the order by ID and it has removed the using temporary but changed it to using filesort and takes much longer to perform the update now.

Comment: The first `EXPLAIN` implies that `ImportID` is part of the `UPDATE`; an oversight when you stripped down the query?

Comment: The `EXPLAINs` end in a comma -- perhaps they were truncated?  Another way (in the commandline tool) is to do `EXPLAIN ... \G` -- this displays vertically.

Comment: (Unrelated)  Packing UUIDs into `BINARY(16)` will save a lot of space.  This may help performance for your large table.  One (of many) pieces of code for such: [packing uuids](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid#code_to_do_it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess:

The `UPDATE` is changing an indexed value (`readyState`), correct?  That means that the index in question is being changed as the `UPDATE` is using it?  So, the `UPDATE` may be "protecting" itself by fetching the rows (in an inefficient way, apparently), tossing them into a tmp table, and only then performing the action.

"Index merge intersect" is almost always less efficient than a composite index:  `INDEX(readyState, productName)` (in either order).  Suggest you add that.

Since you have no `ORDER BY`, which "30" will be unpredictable.  Suggest you add `ORDER BY the-primary-key`.

Comment: It is a reasonable assumption, however I have just tested what happens if I only update not indexed fields but have the same conditions. It unfortunately still uses the exact same index merge and still uses a temporary table.

Comment: as mentioned in the other comments, when I add the Order By ID, the "using temporary" changed to "using filesort" which takes even longer to execute than before.

Comment: Ok, got it working based on your suggestion to add the Index over all of the non primary indexes. I had to also set "Use Index(compositeIndex)" otherwise it was still doing the index merge. It turns out that it still uses Temporary with the new index but it is extremely fast now so does not really matter about the temp table now. Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (There was a significant change in `UPDATE` optimization at some point.)  (I'm finding your question to be quite interesting.)

Comment: This could be an interesting read:  http://oysteing.blogspot.si/2014/07/a-multi-table-trick-to-speed-up-single.html  And it may even give you the desired answer.